# How fix color canvas on android widget with night mode

Tags: android, kotlin, appwidgetprovider

When i'm set my color `#FF222222` in my view in widget, android device with nightmode, change my color to `#FFDDDDDD`

I'd tried to set color in `values-night`, set to

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
```

Comment: Is there a light theme and a dark theme perhaps?